# solr - search with a trailing wildcard does not return the expected results

Tags: solr

I have this document indexed on Solr:

```json
{
    "UUID": "4380",
    "QueryTerm": "stl3023",
    "Type": "unspecified",
    "HitCount": 1,
    "FieldName": "_suggest"
}
```

I am trying to retrieve this document by querying on `QueryTerm` field.

This field is defined as this in the `schema.xml` file:

```xml
<field indexed="true" name="QueryTerm" stored="true" type="textSplitConcat"/>
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSplitConcat" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter catenateAll="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateWords="1" class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateNumberParts="0" generateWordParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If I run a query with these parameters:

```
q=QueryTerm:l3023*
qt=standard
fl=*
q.op=AND
wt=javabin
version=2
```

I get no results.

But if I run a query without the trailing `*` it correctly retrieves the document I need:
[image: query from Solr's admin console]

Why does this happen? Shouldn't the trailing `*` match 0 or more characters (as stated [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-WildcardSearches))?

I'm using Solr version 4.8.1.

The trailing `*` is added automatically by the web application and I'm not able to remove it, so I must get that document even with that trailing `*`. However I am able to change Solr's configuration in `schema.xml` file, if it may help in any way.

---

**EDIT #1**

After @MatsLindh's answer, I have tried to switch from WordDelimiterFilter to NGramFilter:

```xml
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSplitConcat" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="256"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But I still don't get any results when I run the query with the trailing `*`:
[image: query on Solr admin with the trailing wildcard]

This is a screenshot from the analysis tool:
[image: screenshot from Solr admin analysis tool]

I still don't get it. The analysis tool shows a match, but the query does not return any result. What am I not getting about this?

Instead, the query without the trailing wildcard still returns the document.

---

**EDIT #2**

After **EDIT #1** I have not re-indexed my content and that was the problem. Now I have done it and Solr correctly finds the document I expect with the query `QueryTerm:l3023*`.

Comment: You have to reindex your content after changing the analysis chain. There is no need for the wildcard when using ngrams - as you can see on the indexing side, l3023 is already present as a token. `QueryTerm:l3032` should give you a hit by itself. Also, you only want the ngram filter to be present on the indexing analysis chain and not both as is now the case - when it's present on both, any matching letter on either side will give you a hit.

Comment: @MatsLindh The wildcard is appended automatically to the query sent to Solr by the web application and I'm not able to remove it. But you are right: I needed to reindex the content again to see the changes. However I don't understand what do you mean with `you only want the ngram filter to be present on the indexing analysis chain and not both as is now the case`: what should I do then?

Comment: You add two different analysis chains to your definition: `<fieldType ...><analyzer type="index"> ... </analyzer> <analyzer type="query">...</analyzer></fieldType>` - you can see a complete example under Analysis Phases: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/analyzers.html#analysis-phases This allows you to define different analysis chains for indexing and querying.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your suggestion. I've done some tests and I think that in my case it's not a problem to have the same analysis for both. That index provides query term suggestions in an e-commerce website. It's not a problem if any matching letter gives a hit, because if users enter only 1-2 characters in the search box they can't expect a meaningful search. Also, I've seen that Solr does not return all the records by default, so I don't think there could be performance problems. Do you think instead that I should have different analysis for them?

Comment: @MatsLindh I've done more tests and I've found out that even without the NGramFilter for querying, Solr still finds many entries when querying for example with `QueryTerm:x*` (as it should, I think). So what's the point of removing it in my case?

Comment: It'll in effect give you something of the same effect; any document that have a token starting with `x`. If you have a ngramfilter that runs through the whole token, that will match any document with `x` somewhere in the field.

Comment: @MatsLindh Ok, now I understand. So I will leave the NGramFilter also for querying, because a "contains" search is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a wildcard most of the analysis chain is skipped (only filters that are multiterm aware are applied - which means that usually only the `LowercaseFilter`).

In your case the WordDelimiterFilter changes the tokens in a way that there are *no* tokens stored that begins with `l3023`. You can use the Analysis page under the Solr admin to see how the incoming text is processed and see what tokens are generated.

The matching content in your example is `3023` - the `stl` part doesn't generate a hit (and since your query is for `l3023` and not `stl3023` the concatenate part of the word delimiter filter doesn't matter (since the token stored is `stl3023`, not `l3023`.

If you want to perform matches inside a token, you might want to look at generating ngrams instead.

PS: For 8.x you should probably use the graph filter version of the word delimiter filter instead.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion about ngrams, I've tried that filter but it still does not work as I want. I have updated my question.
Maybe the problem is that the NGramFilter also is not "multiterm aware"? How can I know if a filter is "multiterm aware"?

Comment: You don't need wildcards if you're doing ngrams. An ngram filter will generate all combinations for a given token - i.e. `abc` will (depending on your mingrams/maxgrams settings) indexed as `a`, `ab`, `abc`, `b`, `bc`, `c`. If you're changing the indexing time filters you'll need to reindex your content.